# Excel INDEX MATCH when one of multiple criteria is within a range of numbers

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, range, match

To identify duplicates in a large list of personal records, I'm replacing all names with a CONCATENATE of Name and Date of Birth (DOB).  Here is the sheet I'm referencing (DOBs!):

```
DOBs! -----------------------------------------
C               D           E       F       G       I            K
Name            Years       Start   End     # Yrs   DOB          NewNameDOB
Sally Adams     2014-2014   2014    2014    1       1968-1204    Sally Adams1968-1204
John Agnew      2014-2014   2014    2014    1       1979-0419    John Agnew1979-0419  
Bob Anderson    2013-2014   2013    2014    2       1965-0402    Bob Anderson1965-0402  
Antonio Andrews 2014-2014   2014    2014    1       1955-0716    Antonio Andrews1955-0716  
Julie Assan     2012-2014   2012    2014    3       1978-0805    Julie Assan1978-0805
```

On the main sheet (Employees!), each person has a row of data for each active year.  Work 14 years, you have 14 lines of data to track.

```
Employees! -----------------------------------------
C       D               **E**                       F       G   H   I   J...
Year    Name            NewNameDOB                  Dept
2013    Julie Assan     Julie Assan1978-0805        East
1998    Mike Rogers     Duplicate in Same Year      Main
1999    Mike Rogers     Duplicate in Same Year      Main
2000    Mike Rogers     Mike Rogers1969-0510        Main
2001    Mike Rogers     Mike Rogers1969-0510        Main
```

As mentioned, I need to separate duplicate names from 10395 records (like Mike Rogers and Mike Rogers).  **Employees! column E** will now identify the employees as Julie Assan1978-0805 and Julie Assan1980-0131 (for example).

Today we take my first step, using the years they worked in order to solve 99% of the duplicates.  After this, only a few duplicate names will be left who worked at the same time as each other, which I'll have to handle manually.

If the Employees! sheet has a 2013 record for "Julie Assan," then the first step is to check DOBs to find any Julie Assans who worked in 2013.  My new **column E in Employees!** will take the current 2013 record of Julie Assan, and find any matches in DOB! where C (name) matches Julie Assan, E <= 2013, and F >= 2013.  Usually, there will be only one match, and it will tell me that is Julie Assan1978-0805.  Sometimes, there will be two Mike Rogers who worked during the same year, and it should tell me "Duplicate in Same Year".

On the **Employees! sheet column E**, I've started with this...
    =index(DOBs!$k$2:$k$10395,match($d3&$c3,DOBs!$c$2:$c$10395&   ???   ,0)

Not sure where to go with this formula, whether that means adding "IFs" or something different.

*edited to explain in great depth*

Comment: It is not clear what you are aiming for. It will help if you post sample input data, and expected output.

Comment: okay, i've updated with a lot more information.  hopefully this is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(DOBs!C$2:C$10395,Employees!D2,DOBs!E$2:E$10395,"<="&Employees!C2,DOBs!F$2:F$10395,">="&Employees!C2)>1,"Duplicate in Same Year",INDEX(DOBs!K$2:K$10395,MATCH(TRUE,IF(DOBs!C$2:C$10395=Employees!D2,IF(DOBs!E$2:E$10395<=Employees!C2,IF(DOBs!F$2:F$10395>=Employees!C2,TRUE))),0)))
```

Enter as an array formula by confirming with Ctrl+Shift+Enter, then autofill down. It first checks for duplicates using COUNTIFS, and returns "Duplicate in same year" if it is. If there are not duplicates, it uses INDEX/MATCH to find the NewNameDOB.

Comment: thanks, kyle!   I tried as ={IF(COUNTIFS(DOBs!C$2:C$10395,Employees!D2,DOBs!E$2:E$10395,"<="&Employees!C2,DOBs!F$2:F$10395,">="&Employees!C2)>1,"Duplicate in Same Year",INDEX(DOBs!K$2:K$10395,MATCH(TRUE,IF(DOBs!C$2:C$10395=Employees!D2,IF(DOBs!E$2:E$10395<=Employees!C2,IF(DOBs!F$2:F$10395>=Employees!C2,TRUE))),0)))} and also tried adding "="& after that first DOBs!C$2:C$10395... they both came up N/A (Did Not Find value 'TRUE' in MATCH evaluation).

Comment: Is your data different than your sample? I tried my formula with your sample data and it works. Also, I noticed you included curly braces in the formula, Excel inserts those automatically when you confirm with Ctrl+Shift+Enter, you do not want to enter those yourself.

Comment: yes, that was just a small sample... how can I send or upload the current file?  I've got it in Google Sheets and Excel format

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIFS(DOBs!C$2:C$10395,Employees!D2,DOBs!E$2:E$10395,"<="&Employees!C2,DOBs!F$2:F$10395,">="&Employees!C2)>1,"Duplicate in Same Year",INDEX(DOBs!K$2:K$10395,MATCH(TRUE,IF(DOBs!C$2:C$10395=Employees!D2,IF(DOBs!E$2:E$10395<=Employees!C2,IF(DOBs!F$2:F$10395>=Employees!C2,TRUE))),0)))` I had some of the columns mixed up actually. Even though you labeled it perfectly clearly, your starting at C messed me up.

Comment: I edited my answer, use that formula instead of the previous comment. They're exactly the same but for some reason when I copy the formula out of my comment Excel won't take it.

Comment: yeah, that's the formula I'd already been using... I also made the change to add ,"="& where I said.  Both options come up N/A in both google sheets and excel.  How can I upload/send my doc to you?

Comment: If you upload the .xlsx file to somewhere like mediafire I can take a look at it, but I will have to wait until tonight because it will be blocked at work.

Comment: (http://www.mediafire.com/view/6o89pj02db5vn81/Employees.xlsx) Let me know if i need to grant access - I've never used mediafire

Comment: Your years (columns E-F) on the DOBs sheet are stored as text. You can convert them to numbers in Excel by typing 1 in any cell, copying that cell, highlighting those two columns and doing a paste special - multiply.